# How to take in a string or int when Parsing Excel File Cell with NPOI F#

Tags: f#

I am trying to parse an excel file using F#. I am adding a value to a record and the value is float. However in the file that I am parsing I will occasionally get a "#" and I am unable to read in the "#" and it breaks my code.

Pretend that this is a cell that is being called row by row using a Seq.unfold:

```
Cell Value
----------
   5.76
   6.54
   7.85
   8.46
     #
```

The code used to call it is as followed

```
sheet2.GetCell(1).NumericCellValue
```

The code works until it hits a #.
I want to change how to file is saved having 'NaN' value instead of the '#'. How would I write an if statement that would add this but also allow me to keep a double record value?